# Is it possible to define a spring bean backed by a dynamic language in Mule ESB?

Tags: mule

I'm attempting to define a spring bean using  as below:

```
<lang:groovy id="mmmm" name="GroovyRssGeneralTestServer" script-source="${app.home}/groovy/RssGeneralTestServerImpl.groovy">
        <lang:property name="xmlFile" value="${app.home}/rss/GeneralTestServer.xml" />
</lang:groovy>
```

I've tried several different locations for the script-source, but have had no luck in getting mule to find the source for the groovy script.

Second, I'm curious whether I can even wire up a groovy component to use this bean even if I do get it configured correctly above?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying Spring bean when there is a Groovy component in Mule that can execute external Groovy script ? Please refer :- http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Groovy+Component+Reference
and this :-
http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+language+beans+in+Spring

Hope this help

Comment: I want to wire up the bean from the Mule Configuration file, and use the bean as a property of other beans.